# Getting events for a specified time range for a specific calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net, office365, office365api, office365-restapi

I am using [Outlook REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations) to fetch events from Outlook calendar.

The client I am using is [.NET](https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/dotnet) one.

My goal is to fetch events from a **specific** calendar (I have calendarid of the calendar with me) for next 6 months starting from now.

In order to do that I followed this section: [Get events from the user's calendar (Client)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations#GetEventsClient)

I tried achieving fetching events for a calendar for a time range via two different methods:

First, via events collection:

```
 await client.Me.Events[calendarID]
```

[image]

and

Second, via calendars collection

```
await client.Me.Calendars[calendarID].Events
```

[image]

but I am not even able to compile that code since it is giving the error:

> Cannot apply indexing to an expression of type
>   'Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices.ICalendarCollection.

The very first line of that paragraph in their documentation states this:

> To get the events from a different calendar, call the calendar's
>   Events property.

Did I do something wrong in my code?

Does anyone know where is the sample of fetching events from a specific calendar  for a time range?

Does anyone know where is the list of samples for accessing their various other APIs via [.NET](https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/dotnet) client.

I even went here [O365-Win-Snippets/src/Calendar/CalendarSnippets.cs](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Win-Snippets/blob/master/src/Calendar/CalendarSnippets.cs) and couldn't find what I need. There is no sample for fetching events for a specific calendar.

I have already gone through:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34725030/148657

but that addresses only timerange and not specific calendar.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax should be:

```
var myEvents= await client.Me.Calendars[calendarId].Events.ExecuteAsync();
```

Comment: I have already mentioned there in my question I am not able to use this "Calendars[calendarID]", it says cannot apply indexing to an expression of type 'Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices.ICalendarCollection.

Comment: I think the API has changed or the following line "To get the events from a different calendar, call the calendar's Events property." is not correct in the documentation.

Comment: Well after banging my head by decompiling Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices.Portable dll the correct syntax for 
fetching events is: await client.Me.Calendars.GetById(calendarID)                  .Events.ExecuteAsync(); and for calendar view events: await client.Me.CalendarView.GetById(calendarID).Calendar.GetCalendarView(<startdate>, <enddate>).ExecuteAsync(); 
Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: The dll version of Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices.Portable is 2.0.1 at my end which is the latest I got from Nuget.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax resolve for me:

client.Me.GetCalendarView(new DateTimeOffset(dateStart), new DateTimeOffset(dateEnd)); //Returns EventsCollection